# Displaying int variables on an NSString with [[NSString alloc]initWithString

Tags: iphone, nsstring, int

I have and NSString called "health" and i have an int called "healthInt" I m doing this in my Appdelegates because other files have to access it. What i want to do is have the NSString "health" be assigned the value of "healthInt". That way in another class i can set a label to the NSString "health" and have "healthInt" be displayed on that label. Here's the code sorry the code isn't pasting properly.

```
Appdelegate.h

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>{
NSString * health;
int healthInt;
}
-(void)take2Damage;
-(void)tellHealth;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong, nonatomic) ViewController *viewController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * health;
@end

Appdelegate.m

@synthesize health;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:    (NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

health = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:@"%d", healthInt];
```

But doing this gives me the error "Too many arguments to method  call, expected 1, have 2"

I'm an amateur to objective c so try to explain it simply :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want `-initWithFormat:` instead of `-initWithString:`.

Comment: The names of the methods are `initWithFormat:` and `initWithString:`. The colon makes a world of difference.

Comment: That worked but now I have a method "take2Damage". That just subtracts 2 from healthInt when it hits something. I've made a method that does that and i call that method in another class using [appDelegate take2Damage] but the label isn't updating the number of health left. And in app delegate i have healthInt = 100